Subscribing to Real Time Events AWS Amplify GraphQL in Swift
I am trying to build an application in Xcode using Swift. The application is connected to AWS Amplify and I am trying to follow the docs to create a subscription to updates in a DynamoDB table.
I have been able to create and read 'todos' but the subscription setup has me stumped.
Using the instructions on the following link:
https://docs.amplify.aws/swift/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/
The following code below seems to compile although I am not sure if it is correct. Using the exact copy of the amplify docs without the init throws 'class EnableSubscription has no initializers'
If the code below is correct, how can I initialize the subscription?
I am new to this and the documentation seems fairly sparse so any help is much appreciated.
class EnableSubscription {
    var subscription: AmplifyAsyncThrowingSequence<GraphQLSubscriptionEvent<Todo>>
    
    init(subscription: AmplifyAsyncThrowingSequence<GraphQLSubscriptionEvent<Todo>>) {
        self.subscription = subscription
    }
    
    func createSubscription() {
        subscription = Amplify.API.subscribe(request: .subscription(of: Todo.self, type: .onCreate))
        Task {
            do {
                for try await subscriptionEvent in subscription {
                    switch subscriptionEvent {
                    case .connection(let subscriptionConnectionState):
                        print("Subscription connect state is \(subscriptionConnectionState)")
                    case .data(let result):
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let createdTodo):
                            print("Successfully got todo from subscription: \(createdTodo)")
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Subscription has terminated with \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}


You need to call the createSubscription() function either in the init() or anywhere in your app such as a ViewModel if you're using SwiftUI.
You can then handle any state updates in case .success(let createdTodo):
I would personally put this entire function and subscription field into a TodoViewModel and update the todoList in that model whenever I receive an event.
